# rawsql query in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, vertica

I am trying to run `RAWSQL_REAL("select sum(amount_us)from gbsa_dpo_itg.Fact_tblHistoryData_new where qtr_data='Q42014'")` in calculated field and I am getting error message `ERROR 2133:  Aggregate function calls cannot contain subqueries`.

I am using tableau 8.3.3 and HP Vertica database live connection to tableau

When I run the same query in custom sql it is working fine

pleas help in this

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any subqueryes in your SQL statement !

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual about these functions, look under reference, functions

You don't generally pass an entire SQL string to execute in isolation. Instead, they are useful for writing expressions or calling non standard functions that your server may provide, which are embedded within the SQL that Tableau generates. So first learn to use Tableau to get the effect you want, and then resort to Raw SQL functions in the rare case where you need to access some database server specific feature.

There is no reason that you would need Raw SQL to get the information above using Tableau. You could put amount_us on the row shelf and qtr_data on the filter shelf, and Tableau would generate a similar query.

If you are doing this to combine data from multiple queries, first learn about calculated fields and data blending.